# Json response text showing

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here my code in SENCHA TOUCH 2, When i called the json its properly working.But failed to get specific response item by title, here the 
**JSON reponse text**

[image]

**Sencha**

```
var obj = new Object();
                    obj.emailID = 'faz@gmail.com';
                    obj.password = 'faz';
                    var data = Ext.JSON.encode(obj);
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                     url : 'http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/Login',
                                     method : "POST",
                                     headers: {
                                     },
                                     params : data,
                                     useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
                                     withCredentials: true,
                                     success : function(response) {
                                      alert(response.responseText);
                                     },
                                     failure : function(response) {
                                     alert(response.responseText);
                                     }
                                     });
```

How to get userFirstName in from response and show in the alert?Please help me to sort it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var o = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
alert(o[0].userFirstName);
```